# Error al contar filas en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

en el siguiente código me marca un error, trato de comprobar que el registro que se agrega con el nombre de usuario existe o no, para no duplicar campos, pero me arroja el error "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp64\www\RETU_admin.php on line 39"

Dicha linea es la que corresponde a:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($resultado2)==0){
```

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible y sus comentarios.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
$flag=0;
//INICIA CODIGO php *************************************
$host = "localhost";
      $puerto = "3306";
      $usuario = "root";
      $contrasena = "root";
      $baseDeDatos ="retu";
      $tabla = "usuarios";
      function Conectarse()
      {global $host, $puerto, $usuario, $contrasena, $baseDeDatos, $tabla;
         if (!($link = mysqli_connect($host.":".$puerto, $usuario, $contrasena))) 
         { exit(); }
         if (!mysqli_select_db($link, $baseDeDatos)) 
         { exit(); }
      return $link; } 
      $link = Conectarse(); 

//-------------Boton Agregar los datos
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //echo $_POST['username'];
        $uss=$_POST['username'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];
        if ($uss!=null and $pass!=NULL){
            echo "entro 1";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from usuarios where usuario='$uss'") or die (mysql_error());

            if(mysql_num_rows($resultado2)==0){
                /*echo $resultado2;
                $pass1=password_hash(base64_encode(hash('sha384', $pass, true)), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $query1 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,clave) VALUES ($uss,$pass1)");
                header("Location:RETU_ok.php");*/
                echo "no hay dato";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "si hay dato";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
                $flag=1;
                    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
//------------Por aqui es la salida...
if (isset($_POST['descon'])){
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:RETU_door.php");
    }
    // TERMINA CODIGO PHP *******************************************************************
?>

<br>
        <br>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Agregar Usuario:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required autofocus></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Agregar el Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required ></br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" name="descon" class="btn btn-danger">SALIR</button></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">AGREGAR</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php
if($flag==1)
{echo "<font color='red'><b>Faltan datos</b></font>";}
$flag=0;
?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estás usando la función equivocada, cambia `mysql_num_rows` por `mysqli_num_rows`, o sea, **estás omitiendo la `i`** en el nombre final de la función, el código debería quedar así: `if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado2)==0){`

Comment: EXCELENTE,  muchas gracias, si era la "i"... mil gracias a todos.

Comment: De todos modos convendría que mejores tu código, desde organizarlo correctamente hasta aplicar buenas prácticas, como evitar el uso de globales, usar consultas preparadas para prevenir riesgos de seguridad, verificar los valores que son pasados por POST, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Tienes razón @A.Cedano ¿podrías recomendarme alguna lectura al respecto de ese aspecto de seguridad?

Comment: Si buscas aquí mismo el término "Inyección SQL", encontrarás varias preguntas con buenas respuestas sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema creo que reside en la siguiente linea:

```
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from usuarios where usuario='$uss'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Al realizar el `select` con el asterisco * estas indicando que se traiga todos los registros que cumplan la condición de `usuario ='$uss'` y no el numero de registros.

Cambia el `"*"` por `"count(*)"`  y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) from usuarios where usuario='$uss'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.